# Does Natsu still have access to his etherious form and can he still use Fire Dragon King Mode?

Tags: fairy-tail

I've kept up with the Fairy Tail lore and I know that Natsu is end. I also know that the series ended with Natsu kind of killed his brother Zeref while also killing Acnologia.

So after everything's said and done, I was wondering at the end of the manga if he could still tap into his etherious form. Also, can he still use Fire Dragon King Mode or did he lose both of them?

Comment: Before answering your question, what made you think that natsu can't. And information about zeref is not correct, AFAIK, it is not natsu. Can you elaborate your question a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Natsu can tap into his etherious mode, But not whenever. We caught a glimpse at his etherious mode in Fairytail: Dragon's Cry. He was only able to trigger this mode whenever he felt a strong wave of emotion. In the manga series he triggered his etherious mode after seeing (what I can presume as an illusion) of Lucy dying. The anime series hid this mode when future Lucy died (Episode 194-198.) He can also still use his Fire Dragon King Mode, but as he said in the manga, He will use the power given to him by Igneel. He was able to use his mode again without Igneel's power but the results weren't the same. All in All, Yes he can still use both modes, but he needs to obtain that power to activate them by himself (half the way there; already can activate FDKM)